# How to include Laravel model boot "deleting" method into DB transaction with the main model delete?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, transactions

I have a model `Agent` and it has many `agent accounts`.

```
public function agentAccounts(): Relation
{
    return $this->hasMany(AgentAccount::class);
}
```

I want to delete them in one transaction but using `boot` method

```
public static function boot()
{
    parent::boot();

    self::deleting([self::class, 'onDeleting']);
}
```

I understand, that when I create a Db transaction inside "onDeleting" funcion like this

```
public static function onDeleting(self $model): void
{
    DB::transaction(function () use ($model) {
        $agentAccounts = $model->agentAccounts;
        foreach ($agentAccounts as $agentAccount) {
            /* @var $agentAccount AgentAccount */
            $agentAccount->delete();
        }            
    }, 5);
}
```

The db transaction does not include the deletion of the agent itself.
It precedes the agent deletion db transaction.
In my case agent deletion can fail due to some SQL level restrictions not related to agentAccounts
and If I use the exampel above I can end up with all agentAccounts deleted but the Agent - preserved.

I don't want that to happen.

I want them either get deleted together, or be preserved together.

How can I do it?

Comment: I don't believe that this will be possible with model events unless you overwrite the original eloquent methods, any reason you don't want to use `->onDelete('cascade')` on the `AgentAccount` foreign key to `Agent`? That way it will automatically delete all accounts if the agent is successfully deleted.

Comment: Thanks. 'cascade' is not that flexible, I have simplified the question. In reality there are conditions and more tables involved.

Answer (score 0):

I believe DB events are run in a blocking mode, so it's enough when calling the `delete()` on a model, to do it inside of a transaction, like that

```
DB::transaction(function () use($user) { $user->delete(); });
```